# How do you update an existing filter field in an Extension Library and have the UI update with the new value (Inventory Lookup SmartPanel)?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to update the value of the Inventory field inside of an existing PXSmartPanel (the Inventory Lookup screen). I want to be able to set the value of the Inventory field from my Extension library code, and then have that value propagate up to the UI immediately.

With my current code, if I click on an existing UI element in the panel (the "Show Available Items" checkbox), this forces the UI to update and then my value will appear. However, I want to be able to force the UI update from my code. How do I do this? Code is copied below.

I think that perhaps the Base method is not being called in the correct place, but I don't know how to do this from anywhere other than the RowSelected event. Acuminator warns me that I can't call Base.Propogate() from an extension library, and in addition this is not a database bound field, so that also leans against using Propogate to update the value in the UI.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive()
        {
            return true;
        }
        protected void SOSiteStatusFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseMethod)
        {

            if (baseMethod != null)
              baseMethod(sender, e);
        }

        public void SOSiteStatusFilter_Inventory_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            SOSiteStatusFilter myfilter = (SOSiteStatusFilter)e.Row;
            
            sender.SetValueExt<SOSiteStatusFilter.inventory>(myfilter, "798815");
            sender.Update(myfilter);

        }
        public virtual void SOSiteStatusFilter_Inventory_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            SOSiteStatusFilter myfilter = (SOSiteStatusFilter)e.Row;
            if(myfilter != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("inventory filter field update complete");
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Before checkbox click...Inventory filter field is empty:
[image: Before checkbox click]
After checkbox click...Inventory filter field is filled and correct result is found in grid (hardcoded value injected from extension library):
[image: After checkbox click]

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal refresh method in Acumatica. Refresh method depends heavily on context. For example, if you need the popup to refresh when it opens you have to set the value in the delegate parameter of AskExt method.

To do this, first override `AddInvBySite` action:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> addInvBySite;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Items", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXLookupButton]
public virtual IEnumerable AddInvBySite(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    sitestatusfilter.Cache.Clear();
    if (sitestatus.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
    {
        return AddInvSelBySite(adapter);
    }
    sitestatusfilter.Cache.Clear();
    sitestatus.Cache.Clear();
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Then add the delegate parameter to initialize popup values:

```
if (sitestatus.AskExt((graph, viewName) => 
   { 
      sitestatus.Current?.inventory = "XYZ"; 
   }) == WebDialogResult.OK) 
{
  ...
}
```

Other context requires other refresh methods:

- To refresh on field updated UI events  you need to set property `CommitChanges="True"` on ASPX control declaration.
- To refresh parent page after popup closes that would be attribute
  property OnClosingPopup set to Refresh or Cancel: `[PXLookupButton(OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Refresh)]`
- Some edge cases can be resolved by explicitly requesting dataview refresh `sitestatus.View.RequestRefresh()`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Hugues. I think what's confusing is that this particular field already refreshes the attached grid view when you type into the Inventory filter field, by directly populating values in the Select2 query attached to the PXProjection. Acumatica's docs say that SetValueExt is supposed to trigger the same event handlers as if the user had performed the action, but in this case that doesn't happen.

Comment: Hugues... adding CommitChanges="True" solved my issue. Thank you! I had actually seen where you had proposed this solution before, but I thought this field must already be using that feature since it was updating on demand in response to user input.

Comment: This popup probably uses ClientEvents and Javascript code on the UI layer which explains why there's a response to user generated events. You still need CommitChanges to have the callback to the Graph layer.

Comment: I know Acumatica is working on a new front-end based on Typescript. I think that is a great idea. By far, the biggest downside of the platform at the moment is the lack of control over Javascript events and the relatively poor support for implementing one's own Javascript inside the platform.